# Invalid address: xyz@opruss.com ,xyz@opruss.com Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.There was an error

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$thismessage=base64_encode($htmlmsg);
$subject="Grups Automation siemens and sick sensor Product";
$mail->SMTPDebug= 2;
$mail->IsSMTP();                                    //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
$mail->Host = 'My hosting server';                  //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
$mail->Port = '465';                                //Sets the default SMTP server port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
$mail->Username = 'enquiry@grupsautomation.co.in';  //Sets SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                         //Sets SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
$mail->setFrom ('grups@xyz.in','Grups automation'); //Sets the From email address for the message
$mail->AddAddress($email_id);                       //Adds a "To" address
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                               //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $htmlmsg;

if ($mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Mail Sent';
    $sql = 'UPDATE `email_demo` SET `html_sub`="'.$subject.'", `html_body`="'.$thismessage.'",`sending_time`="'.time().'", `status` = "1" ,email_track_code="'. $track_code.'" WHERE `id` = "'.$id.'"';
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo 'Database updated successfully';
    } else {
        echo 'Error updating database: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    }
} else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo 'There was an error';
}
```

This is my code and it is working for @gmail.com example : xyz@gmail.com but the same code is not working for domain specific email like xyz@infotech.com. And the email id getting from the database.

I want the solution that why this same code working for @gmail.com and not for other. Please tell the what the problem in the code and how to solve this

Comment: The error messge in your title suggests you are trying to send to 1 address with a whitespace on the end, followed by a comma, followed by a 2nd address: `Invalid address: xyz@opruss.com ,xyz@opruss.com`.  But your question says nothing about 2 addresses, and sounds like simply a GMail spam problem.  Which is it?

Comment: FYI: Setting a `From` address that doesn't actually match the SMTP account you are using to send, is a pretty good way to end up in spam filters; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux `From:` sender"

Comment: Please be warned that your `UPDATE` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1):

As always, the first thing to do is read the error message, which says that the address you are trying to use is:

```
xyz@opruss.com ,xyz@opruss.com
```

which is obviously not a valid address. Check the data you are passing in, and also note that `addAddress` returns `false` if you try to use an invalid address; you don't have to wait until calling `send()` to find out that it's invalid.

Comment: sir that is the example... i cant share my clien email thats why i wrote like this

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a fake address - an email address followed by a space, a comma, and another email address is not a valid email address.

Answer (score -1):

try change from `$mail->AddAddress($email_id);` to `$mail->AddAddress($email_id, '');`

Comment: tried but still same problem

Comment: you mistyped the addAddress in your code.
must be `$mail->addAddress($email_id);`

Comment: changed but same error sir